Improve speed of IDA* and heuristic algorithm
I am creating a Rubik's cube CFOP solver. Right now I am working on the F2L part of the CFOP method. I decided to use IDA* and heuristics to find the solution to each pair individually. I have managed to make a solver that solves some F2L cases, but there are some cases that the algorithm just takes a bit too long to solve.
Here is the IDA* algorithm I use:
class IDA_star(object):
    def __init__(self, corners, edges, max_depth=20):
        self.max_depth = max_depth
        self.moves = []
        self.transposition_table = {}
        self.corners = corners
        self.edges = edges

    def run(self, cube):
        threshold = heuristic_value(cube, self.corners, self.edges)
        while threshold <= self.max_depth:
            self.moves = []
            self.transposition_table = {}
            distance = self.search(cube, 0, threshold)
            if distance == True:
                return self.moves
            if distance == float('inf'):
                return None
            threshold = distance
        return None

    def search(self, cube, g_score, threshold):
        cube_state = self.get_cube_state(cube)

        if cube_state in self.transposition_table:
            stored_g_score, stored_result = self.transposition_table[cube_state]
            if stored_g_score <= g_score:
                return stored_result

        f_score = g_score + heuristic_value(cube, self.corners, self.edges)
        if f_score > threshold:
            self.transposition_table[cube_state] = (g_score, f_score)
            return f_score

        if is_goal_state(get_cross_state(cube), get_edge_state(cube, self.edges), get_corner_state(cube, self.corners), self.corners, self.edges):
            self.transposition_table[cube_state] = (g_score, True)
            return True

        min_cost = float('inf')
        for action in range(18):
            cube_copy = copy.deepcopy(cube)
            cube_copy = actions(action, cube_copy)

            self.moves.append(action)
            distance = self.search(cube_copy, g_score + 1, threshold)
            if distance == True:
                return True
            if distance < min_cost:
                min_cost = distance
            self.moves.pop()

        self.transposition_table[cube_state] = (g_score, min_cost)
        return min_cost

    def get_cube_state(self, cube):
        return (tuple(cube.cp), tuple(cube.co), tuple(cube.ep), tuple(cube.eo))


Here is also the heuristic function that determines the heuristic value:
def heuristic_value(cube, corners, edges):
    stateEdge = get_edge_state(cube, edges)
    stateCross = get_cross_state(cube)
    stateCorner = get_corner_state(cube, corners)

    h_corner = tableLoader.heurUBR.get(stateCorner, 6)
    h_edge = tableLoader.heurBR.get(stateEdge, 6)
    h_cross = tableLoader.heurCross.get(stateCross, 7) - 1

    # Weighted sum
    weighted_sum = (3 * h_corner + 2 * h_cross + h_edge) / 6

    h_value = max(h_corner, h_cross, h_edge, weighted_sum)

    return h_value

The heuristic function is very basic and I think it could be better.
I have already tried implementing a transposition table and it has worked very good it decreased the time of an average solution from 500 seconds to around 50 seconds which is very good, but still I need it to find solutions faster. I have 3 main heuristics the Rubik's cube cross edges containing around 59k cases (I know that there are at least 190k, but that would take some time to generate which I plan to do in the future), I have a heuristic for the F2L pair cross and the corresponding edge heuristic in total that makes 3 heuristic databases. I have also tried implementing memoization, but for some reason when I save the newly found case to a different table, when I run it again it never finds the solution, I have no idea why that happens, but I didn't look much in to that.
My question is, are there any other optimization techniques to use so that my IDA* algorithm performs faster?
